# Excel VBA for Duplicate Conditional Merge and Sum

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for vba excel where column A `Code No.` has duplicate data which needs to be merged in a single row,

column C `Unit` has different unit types (SET,BOX,PCS), to merge duplicate rows check for high qty in column D `Qty` the unit corresponding to highest qty is the unit to consider for merger row.

Finally sum of qty

[image: sample input and output data expected]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: No need for VBA , you can do this with formulas , index,match,max,sumif !